# What is the problem in the networking code below?

Tags: c, linux, networking

I have written these 2 programs, they are supposed to be a netcopy network program, but they won't work. Not quite segfault, but on the receive copy of the network, the file out.bin has length 0, not the size of the sent file. I don't know where is the error, so ... please help. Thank you !

https://pastebin.com/uXTNCRGC
https://pastebin.com/F6rwj09X

```
f = fopen(argv[2], "w+");
int file_no = fileno(f);

printf("sizeof buffere = %d\n", sizeof(buffer));

while(count = read(file_no, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0) {
    write(sockfd, buffer, count);
    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
}
```

// copy.c - the client

```
f = fopen("out.bin", "w+");
int file_no = fileno(f);
while( n = read(connfd, binbuff, sizeof(binbuff)) > 0) {
    write(file_no, binbuff, n);
    bzero(binbuff, sizeof(binbuff));
}
fflush(f);
fclose(f);
exit(1);
```

// netcopy.c - the server

Comment: `f = fopen(argv[2], "w+");` empties the file. Use `f = fopen(argv[2], "r");` to read from the file.

Comment: my mistake : while ( (n= read...) > 0) and while ( (count = read...) > 0)